# cscope/ctags navigation in Intellij Idea vim plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ideavim

I am used to navigating code in vim using cscope/ctags style Ctrl + [ for function definition and Ctrl + t to go back. With Intellij Idea's vim plugin enabled, I am still able to do that. However, other cscope commands like Ctrl + \ s don't seem to work.

I could try adding .ideavim to add my own mapping, but I am looking for something that does not require this step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cscope` is not one of the [emulated plugins](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#emulated-vim-plugins). You can use [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html) navigation to reach that.

Also, you can map keys to [standard idea actions](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#executing-ide-actions).

For example, to get all callers of the method you can execute [Call Hierarchy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/building-call-hierarchy.html) action. You can map this action to `ctrl-\ s` as follows:

- Search for actions with `hierarchy` pattern: `:actionlist hierarchy`
- Place `map <C-\>s :action CallHierarchy<CR>` to your `.ideavimrc`

If you want this behavior to be the default, you can create a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM).