# How to disable function overloading detection in CLion for code navigation?

Tags: c, clion, code-navigation

I'm using CLion to write mostly C code, in `*.c` files. How may I disable the IDE from interpreting the code as C++ for the code navigation feature, so that I can navigate symbols by name only, disregarding the parameters used in function calls? I'd like a more Vim-like experience, like when usings `ctags` and `cscope`, so that when I'm refactoring functions return types and parameters the IDE don't get lost.

Or should I just accept it's the way it works and rely more heavily on the various refactor wizards it provides?

Comment: It's not very clear what behavior you want. How do you see that it's interpreting C as C++ (is the language set in CMakeLists)? How is the current navigation different?

Comment: I want ctags like behavior, where only the symbol name is relevant for finding references or implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for this moment, ctags-like navigation doesn't exist in CLion: [cscope/ctags navigation in Intellij Idea vim plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386205/cscope-ctags-navigation-in-intellij-idea-vim-plugin).

Your assumption that IDE is parsing the C code as C++ is either based on an error in the project's `CMakeLists.txt` or is simply wrong. It uses correct C syntax to navigate C code. Probably you mean C linking rules, where only function name matters.

Yes, I advice that you try the built-in refactorings. They may choke on `#ifdef`-ed out code, because parsing ALL the variants of conditional compilation at the same time is hardly doable, but they are good. You might never look back.